# How can I open specific device in pyaudio based on USB physical port?

Tags: python, usb, pyaudio

In my application I have 4 camera modules (one mic in each) (same vendorid and productid) connected to a Ubuntu linux system.
I want to connect to all 4 mics and identify which channel correspond with specific camera module which is connected in a particular USB physical path (e.g 2-1.3 -> USB bus 2 - Port 1 - Port 3)

How can I (by python code) get the input_device_index for a particular USB device based on his route?

Answer (score 0):

At least four years ago there there was no way to do that. Not on Linux nor Windows. I could imagine only somehow kick out audio driver and read sound directly from USB endpoints but this is crazy solution...